# Java: Check if exists three or more matches in array

Tags: java, arrays

I wish to make a function that checks whether theres any number in the array that exist three or more times.

So example this array:

> 4 - 6 - 14 - 8 - 6 - 15 - 14 - 15 - 13
>   - 10 -

Shouldnt output anything, but this:

> 4 - 6 - 14 - 8 - 6 - 15 - 14 - 15 - 14
>   - 10 -

Should systemout print output that the number 14 exists three times.

How should this be done? I started making a for loop,

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
}
```

And then I got stuck, how can i make this?

Comment: What do you think you should do?  Have you heard of a histogram?

Comment: No I havent. I think i should make some kind of an if statement that checks and stores something somehow. @vidstige homework? no

Comment: Do You know what is the greatest number in that array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                count++;
            }

        }
        if (count >= 3) {
            System.out.println(array[i] + " exists " + count
                    + " times.");
        }
    }
}
```

This programm outputs n times (for n >= 3) that the an element exists n times. You should add a logic that checks whether an element has already been checked. But maybe you can go on by yourself now. Hint: Use a HashMap or a List... or....

Other solution that needs `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` and is faster:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5 };

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    if (array[i] != null) {
        int compare = array[i].intValue();
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

            if (array[j] != null) {
                if (compare == array[j]) {
                    array[j] = null;
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }
        if (count >= 3) {
            System.out
                    .println(compare + " exists " + count + " times.");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 exists 4 times.
2 exists 3 times.
3 exists 3 times.
```

So copy your array into a Integer[] array first. The latter algorithm fixes also the problem with the output.

Comment: This is good, but the question was about "three or more times", so you should perhaps adjust it a bit to satisfy this.

Comment: What is the computation complexity for this algorithm?

Comment: should be something like O(n^2) where n is the number of the array elements. (you can do better, i know :)

Comment: @Simon thanks for your answer. I tested this and only problem is that it is outputting the text, "x exists y times", y times.. so i get if a number exists 4 times it shows this output 4 times.. I only want it to say it once.

Comment: You are capable to do this with two (three to display) for loops but not nested.

Answer (score 3):

simply make a `hashmap` of numbers with numbers value as key and the occurrence times as map value.
after the for loop you can iterate over the map and print the numbers whose occurrence value is more than 3

Comment: I think hashmap is overhead in this case, Simons solution seems fine

Comment: @cOmrade - @Manoj's solution is `O(N)` in time, `O(N)` in space.  @Simon's solution is `O(N^2)` in time, `O(1)` in space.

Comment: Vash's solution is O(n log n) time O(1) space.

Answer (score 1):

you can sort the array and then check for each new element if the next two elements are the same. if they do - save the element. if they don't reset the counter and go to the next element

Answer (score 1):

You could start with sorting the array, then start checking the i with i+1, if are equal then you increment counter otherwise you set him to 0, you repeat this until counter is not equal 2.

```
private static int findTree(int[] array){


        Arrays.sort(array);

        int i = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        while (counter != 2 && i < array.length - 1) {

            if(array[i] == array[i+1]){
                counter++;
            } else {
                counter =0;
            }

            i++;
        }

        if(counter == 2){
            return array[i];
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

EDIT:

More tricky alg, that find n matches of given number.

The assumption is that you have to find at lest n equal numbers.

If we sort our array first, we will have all elements in order, so if we need to find four (n) equal elements we can take one (i) and check the element that is distanced three spaces from him (i+n-1). If this element is equal we found our solution under i element in array if not we can move to next one by incrementing i by one (i++).

And this is how it goes:

```
private static int findN(int[] array, int n){

        if(n == 0) {
         return -1;
        }

        Arrays.sort(array);

        n--; //We reduce our n searched element because in i we already have one

        int i = 0;
        boolean found = false;

        while (found == false && i < array.length - n) {
            if(array[i] == array[i+n]) { //remember that we have reduced the n by one.
                found = true;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        if(found) {
           return array[i];
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for the general case: Search in a list for every Element whether there are X occurences following.

```
public class TripleTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] list = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4};
        findCount (list, 3);
    }

    public static void findCount (int[] list, int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= list.length - count; ++i)
        {
            int elem = list [i];
            boolean hit = findWhatCountFrom (list, i + 1, elem, count - 1);
            if (hit) 
                System.out.println ("hit: " + elem);
        }
    }

    public static boolean findWhatCountFrom (int[] list, int idx, int what, int count)
    {
        if (count == 0)
            return true;
        if (idx == list.length) 
            return false;
        return findWhatCountFrom (list, idx + 1, what, count - ((list [idx] == what) ? 1 : 0));
    }
}
```

It doesn't stop after one solution, so maybe you like to change that. The requierements wheren't clear. Instead of a return value, the solution is printed out - that's a bit ugly.

Improve the solution by changing it from int[] to Generics. Maybe from Array to List.

Answer (score 0):

What if a number exists 4 times?

- No output, because 3 is not 4, you
  want exactly 3
- 1x output, because
  you search for at least 3 hits
- 2x output, because you can show 3
  triples

Answer (score 0):

What if more than one number exists 3 or more times?

- Report every number
- Report the first, only